# Join 2 tables using a column with duplicate values; considering the 1st row

Tags: sql-server

[image]

[image]

I want to join the `EMP` and `SAL` table using `ID` column. In case of duplicate `ID`s in `Sal` table take the 1st row with corresponding `ID` of `sal`. The result should be:

[image]

Comment: First based on what? Your first 2 records in sal are exactly the same...

Comment: and how will you define that row number as I see, you don't have any identity column in your SAL table.

Answer (score 3):

Use the window function `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT SAL.ID, SAL.Gross, Sal.Net, Sal.Deductions, Emp.Name FROM EMP JOIN 
(SELECT *, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Net) rown FROM SAL
) SAL on EMP.ID = SAL.ID
WHERE SAL.rown = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can manage this with `row_number` window function:

```
select * from emp e
join (select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by(select null)) rn from sal ) s 
  on e.id = s.id and s.rn = 1
```